# Total energy of a body following circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I learned that when a body rotates, its total energy is,

$$energy=\left(\frac12\right)mv^2 + \left(\frac12\right)I\omega^2 $$

However, if an astronomical object is orbiting around the earth, is there any rotational kinetic energy? or is it purely translational?

Comment: You have just answered your own question with the equation posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a satellite of mass $m$ at a distance $r$. If we assume the satellite is small enough to behave as a point mass the moment of inertia of the satellite is:

$$ I = m r^2 $$

so its kinetic energy is:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2} I w^2 = \tfrac{1}{2} m r^2 \omega^2 \tag{1}$$

But for a body moving in a circle of radius $r$ at an angular velocity $\omega$ we have the identity;

$$ v = r\omega $$

where $v$ is the tangential velocity. If we substitute for $r\omega$ in equation (1) we get:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2}m v^2 $$

which is of course just the usual equation for kinetic energy. So you can treat the energy of the satellite either as rotational kinetic energy or translational kinetic energy as you find convenient.

This only works because the satellite is small enough compared to the Earth that we can assume every point is moving at the same tangential velocity. If you have some large object pivoting around a point within it, e.g. a disk rotating about its centre, the tangential velocity of all the points in the object will vary with distance from the pivot. In that case it's simpler to assume the angular form for the kinetic energy.